# Replacing __iter__ on a Python class instance doesn't result in the new function being called

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to alter the `__iter__` method on a Python class instance. It seems like a straightforward operation:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class A(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 'i'
        yield 'am'
        yield 'A'

    def newIter(self):
        yield 'i'
        yield 'am'
        yield 'new'

    def changeIter(self):
        self.__iter__ = self.newIter

a = A()
a.changeIter()

print(a.__iter__)
print(list(a))
```

However, in both CPython 2.7.2 and 3.4.1 this prints:

```
<bound method A.newIter of <__main__.A object at 0x10317ecd0>>
['i', 'am', 'A']
```

The first `print` seems to confirm that `a.__iter__` has indeed been changed. So why is the new function not called?  The above works fine for regular methods, so I guess `__iter__` is special in some way (at least in CPython), but how/why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, it is a [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) and special methods are always looked up in the class not instance.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary  I guess I'm just going to have to define my own `iter` for my classes. I don't find the reasoning in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup very convincing. Anyway....